# Right clicking does not work in desktop

Tags: 10.04, nautilus

When I right-click on my Lucid desktop, the context menu does not appear. I mean the menu with options to create a launcher, change desktop background etc. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [gtweakui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gtweakui) [image: Install gtweakui]

Then goto **System > Preferences > gTweakUI-Nautilus**.

[image]

Under the **Desktop**, check **Use Nautilus to draw desktop**.

**Alternate Way:**

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor` and click run.
- Navigate to `apps/nautilus/preferences` on the right side you will see **show_desktop** be sure you have check mark there.
- You can execute the following command in terminal instead,
  `gconftool-2 --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop --type bool 1`
- This will enable right click in your Desktop.

Comment: `Chethan S:` Check my alternate solution.